# how to remove the hamburger menu firefox v83.0

Tags: firefox

I'm a noobie here looking some assistance.

I'm trying to limit a user's access to the three lined menu on the top right hand side of the browser (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04)

I've tried creating a policies.json in the distribution folder in the lib/firefox folder.

> https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1226326

I've also tried editing the userChrome.css file as well

> https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/998356

Neither of these solutions worked for me?

Is there another way that I could do this?

Thank you for any help you may give.

Comment: There's a thread [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=947301) to Buzilla and was closed 11 months ago. I don't think it was a runner with Mozilla so seems like a dead duck to me.

Comment: This really sucks, is there really no way to do this? Sad but still thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to add userChrome.css this CSS Rules
It's from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/998356

```css
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

#PanelUI-menu-button {display: none;}
```

To Enable userChrome.css you could access it here
https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html

It consist of 4 step :
(1) Open your currently active profile folder
(2) Create a new folder named chrome
(3) Create a new text file inside the chrome folder named userChrome.css
(4) Set Firefox to look for userChrome.css at startup (updated 5/24/2019)

I did that to disable megabar and hamburger menu, and yes It works well on 84.0.2 64bit windows 10 20H2

BONUS : Disable MegaBar Generator (https://www.userchrome.org/megabar-styling-firefox-address-bar.html)

It's all other people works so I just want to make sure I just repost it here.

You could comment below if it's not working. let me help you.